# NullPointerException when attempting to start JWS application

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-web-start

I am trying to start the JNLP located at http://gparyani.com/beatbox.jnlp, but I get a NullPointerException in an internal class when I try to do so:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.showSandboxDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.checkSignedSandboxSecurity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.isPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here's the JNLP:

```xml
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://gparyani.com/">
  <information>
    <title>BeatBox</title>
    <vendor>Gaurav Paryani, Nick Hoang, and Harrison Qi</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <update check="background" policy="prompt-run"/>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="beatbox.jar" main="true"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.gparyani.beatbox.GUIMaker"/>
</jnlp>
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Please post more of your code and we won't be able to help you, especially as I see to get a different error than yours.

Comment: @haylem I have the code here: http://sdrv.ms/16XYzZ4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly not the most helpful error message is it.

I was able to get past it by fixing the codebase URL.  Your actual code is hosted at:

`http://www.rohitleena.com/gparyani/`

but the codebase in your JNLP file is:

`http://gparyani.com/`

In summary the fix is to modify the jnlp element in your JNLP file to:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://www.rohitleena.com/gparyani/">
```

This was detected as a warning by [Janela](http://pscode.org/janela/) which may help you debug these issues in the future.

By changing the codebase to the first URL the NullPointerException went away.  My suspicion is that it is trying to validate the URL using certificates and that certificate validation is getting confused when trying to figure out which URL it needs to validate.

Fixing this gets past the NullPointerException and immediately throws another exception but that appears to be a different problem (your application requesting the change the default runtime handler without having the permissions to do so).

Comment: My code does change the top-level error-handler. Is this a disallowed permission?

Comment: There were some others trying to run the JNLP but receiving a different error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gparyani.beatbox.GUIMaker`

Comment: It is not disallowed but it is required and not granted by default.  It allows an attacker to interfere with the shutdown of a program.  I don't know why you would get a ClassNotFoundException.  I am unable to reproduce that.

Comment: If I can't change the default top-level error handler, am I still allowed to do it on a thread-by-thread basis (using `someThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()`)?

Comment: No.  You can sign your JNLP and give it a security element as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947458/java-how-to-get-permission-in-java-web-start .  Or you could avoid setting the default exception handler (could you just surround all your runnables with try/catch or do you not have control over all of them?).  Also, the Java API docs are very clear about when security exceptions can be thrown.

Comment: I did, but that doesn't change the options available.  You can either add the permission request to your JNLP or you can put try/catch statements around your action listeners and your enum constructor.  It appears you already have try/catch statements around some of these.  Also, calling stop on the current thread is dangerous and will cause a security exception of its own.  You should throw a runtime exception instead.

Comment: How can I fix my code so that there are no problems regarding security policy violations?

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.  When you hit a security policy violation your only choices are to modify the JNLP to request that permission or to find some way to not call that method.

Comment: Speaking of the `NullPointerException`, this seems like a bug to me and I'll file it on http://bugreport.sun.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about bug in Java, found this text on many blogs. 
How I solved this:
I was able to launch other Jenkins slave node with name "WinXp-32bit-101" in WinXP Machine, with same Java version. But other node which i have created for Win7 machine with the name "win7-64bit - 113" I am not able to launch at Win7 machine with the same error.
I tried the same launching at WinXp machine and got the same error. 
I also tried launching old node "WinXp-32bit-101" in win7 machine and it worked there.

This means error is not with Java, not even with windows OS version as same error in both machine.

Solution:
I just compared the configuration differences for both the nodes and removed the spaces in name.
From "win7-64bit - 113" to "win7-64bit-113"

and it worked.

How this will help to others as well