# Java webstart is replacing my logging formatter

Tags: java, java-web-start, java.util.logging

I have a logging.properties file that I load at runtime into my java application:

```
final InputStream logFileInputStream= this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("mylogging.properties");
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(logFileInputStream);
```

This logging.properties file specifies a custom formatter:

```
.level = INFO
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = mycustom.logging.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ./logs/blubb.%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 31
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = mycustom.logging.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINEST
```

This works well when run from the commandline. 
However, when starting the application with Java Webstart, the formatters are replaced by SimpleFormatter for the ConsoleHandler and XMLFormat for the FileHandler.
The logging.properties is still being read as for example the logfiles name pattern is respected.

How can I avoid Webstart replacing my formatters?!

Comment: Are all classes included in the jar? Are all required jars with those logger classes in your jnlp?

Comment: @StefanHegny Yes. This custom Formatter is in an additional jar that is included in the JNLP.

Comment: Hmm, anything suspicious in the java console when you start the jnlp? As you seem pretty sure it picks up the properties file, you should maybe check the jars/jnlp again, maybe add them to the question.

Comment: [LogManager.readConfiguration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration(java.io.InputStream)) requires `LoggingPermission("control")` when running under the security manager.  By Default, WebStart runs under the security manager and console does not.

Comment: Another possible issue is that the LogManager can only see system and boot classes.  Write some debug code to print classloader of `mycustom.logging.OneLineFormatter` all of parent classloaders.

Comment: @jmehrens Ah, that may be possible. How do I set the LoggingPermission to "control"? Do I have to modify a policy file on the client computers? Or is there a way to provide this on the server side?

Comment: [java-how-to-get-permission-in-java-web-start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947458/java-how-to-get-permission-in-java-web-start)

Comment: @jmehrens The manifest in the jar already requires all-permissions

Comment: @radlan The link I posted talks about modifying the JNPL file not the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same problem. I can't tell how to stop Webstart replacing the formatter (or why it doesn't recognize it in the first place). Couldn't find a solution for it, but finally that's how I get things working for me with Webstart. I simply reassigned my custom formatter (LoggerFormatter) to the handlers during runtime:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conf/logging.properties");
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(is);
Handler[] handlers = Logger.getGlobal().getParent().getHandlers();
Formatter formatter = new LoggerFormatter();
for (Handler h : handlers) {
    h.setFormatter(formatter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[LogManager.readConfiguration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration(java.io.InputStream)) requires `LoggingPermission("control")` when running under the security manager. By Default, WebStart runs under the security manager and console does not.  It is likely that your configuration is rejected rather than your formatters being replaced.

Try granting `LoggingPermission("control")` in your [JNLP file as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947458/java-how-to-get-permission-in-java-web-start).